Getting Error: Minified React error #130 on running build command in nextjs website
I have updated the node to 20.11.1, react to 18.2.0 and next to 14.1.4. also updated all the dependencies to the latest version in my nextjs website. now on running npm run build and getting the error:
**Minified React error #130; 
visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings** for every page.

I have tried downgrading some of the dependencies, but it is not working; I also tried removing .next, node_modules, and package-lock.json, which didn't work neither.
